# How to order a custom filter prior to spring security debug filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }
}
```

When spring security debugging is enabled, it registers the spring security [DebugFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/debug/DebugFilter.java)

I've a custom filter that I would like to be ordered before the spring security DebugFilter. What would be the most appropriate way for me to have my filter called prior to the debug filter?

My custom filter is already orders before the spring security filter chain, but it doesn't get called before the spring security debug filter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not clear how you specify the order of your custom filter, I assume that you are using Springboot and using *FilterRegistrationBean* to set your custom filter and setting the order by calling setOrder. The below answer is based on that assumption and this may be applicable if you are setting order in a different way as well.

If you look at the source code of *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*, the order applied is 100.

```
@Order(100)
public abstract class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements
        WebSecurityConfigurer<WebSecurity> {
```

So if you want to set the top priority for your custom filter add the following priority using the *FilterRegistrationBean.setOrder* method. Set the highest order using FilterRegistrationBean.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE.

```
filterRegBean.setOrder(FilterRegistrationBean.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
```